# How can I specify a group of contacts that I want to look for in my intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I am currently requesting the list of contacts via

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_CONTACT);
```

Which currently shows all the contacts. However, I would like to filter this list of contacts down to a set of contacts that are part of a specific group or that are part of a specific company. How can I do this / in other words: how can I add a filter or query to the intent to only show the contacts of a specific group or to show the contacts of a specific company?